# How to open my IOS application after selecting word(s) in Kindle?

Tags: ios, kindle

I developed an IOS app that can copy to the clipboard.

I also have the Kindle App, and when I am reading an ebook, I can select a word to find its definition.

Does anybody know how I can associate my IOS app with the Kindle app?

I would like my users to be able to select a word via the Kindle app, and then my app is chosen to look up the selected word.

Thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it using UIActivityViewController. I think you saw it before. Looks like this:

[image]

So you can pass your text there and the user may choose your app.

Code example:

```
let shareText = "Hello, world!"
let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [shareText], applicationActivities: [])
present(vc, animated: true)
```

Hope it helps! Please let me know if you have other questions.

Comment: This is not what the OP is asking. The question is asking how to make their app appear inside the Kindle app when the user highlights a word in the Kindle app.

Comment: As I understand correctly, you are asking how can ur app shown in ActivityController like WhatsApp, Facebook etc..